# setting dynamic 'value' to <textarea> with ruby/sinatra/activerecords

Tags: html, ruby, forms, activerecord, sinatra

I need some help with a simple blog I'm making using Ruby, Sinatra, and ActiveRecords.

I am trying to set a dynamic default 'value' to a  input form, to allow users to edit their blog post without having to retype the whole thing.

This is what I have got so far:

```
<textarea type="comment" id="description" name="description" value="<%= @blog.description %>"></textarea>
```

If I change `<textarea>` to `<input>` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<textarea>` does not have a `value` attribute.

You should change it to read like this:

```
<textarea type="comment" id="description" name="description"><%= @blog.description %></textarea>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, but that still doesn't save the previous information kept in @blog.description.

Comment: I'd recommend accepting this answer and asking a separate question for further help. Given the information that you asked in your question, I cannot guess what else you're trying to do and why it may not be working. This is the way StackOverflow works: you solve one problem at a time (or else feel the wrath of the community. ;))

Comment: Thanks Chris! I understand. Your answer was correct, i just hadn't closed a html tag that was bugging my code. It was late hah!
Cheers,